# Is it possible to find a pre-built rocket in my galacticraft world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

I was playing my Galacticraft/ICBM world the other day, and I looked on my ICBM radar and saw a Tier 1 rocket a couple meters away. I went and looked around, but nothing was there.

Is the rocket underground in some secret chamber, or is it a glitch in ICBM?

http://wiki.micdoodle8.com/wiki/Galacticraft

http://voltzwiki.com/wiki/ICBM

Here are some useful links. Thanks!

Comment: Can it detect it in item form inside chests? Are you sure it's a galacticraft rocket?

Comment: This question is a little vague about which mod the Tier 1 rocket is from; I would assume it is from ICBM since I've never heard of a pre-built Galacticraft rocket being loot. Also, it would help to have wiki links to the items you're describing, as I can't find an ICBM radar, or any item which has the functionality you describe.

Comment: im seeing this on my radar station too
http://puu.sh/bnpDz/b23e02d6f3.png
but theres nothing there, i flew up and i dug down to bedrock, nothing

Comment: That information you added doesn't help your question any.  If you know where to find it, you can post your own answer.  If you don't, adding extraneous information isn't the way to do it.  If you really want an answer, you can always add a bounty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to find a pre-built Galacticraft rocket in your world. Even though it might show up on your radar station (puu.sh/bnpDz/b23e02d6f3.png), there is nothing there.